# Where is the shopify editable html?

Tags: shopify

In a traditional website I would simply open the 'contact' page and add the line then upload. But i'm having difficulty understand the multiple components of shopify's theme, sections, snippets.

So my question is if I want to add a simple text line say in the homepage, where would I add this html?

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the theme you are using. A lot of modern themes have draggable sections which can be accessed via Themes - Customize.

If your theme doesn't have this functionality, or any functionality to add text to the homepage, I'd be surprised. But if you need to edit it by editing the code directly you can access the pages via Themes - Actions - Edit Code. The homepage will usually have a name of `index.liquid`.

Rather than just adding your text in there, though, I recommend you learn how to add snippets and sections to your website. It makes future edits much easier and doesn't take long at all to learn.

1. [The beginner's guide to building shopify themes with sections](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/the-beginner-s-guide-to-building-shopify-themes-with-sections)
2. [Shopify: Theme Sections](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/sections)